# Graph of $\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, continuity, inverse-function

Plot the Graph of $f(x)=\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$

Sol: We see that $$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-(1-x^2)}}\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
$\implies$
$$f'(x)=\frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Now its evident that $$f'(0^+)=1,f'(0^-)=-1$$
But $f'(0)$ is not defined and $f(0)=0$. Do we say this is removable discontinuity of $f'(x)$? How will this information be conveyed in graph?

Comment: Hint: This function is equal to $\sin^{-1}|x|.$

Comment: How is $f’(0^-)=1?$ When $x<0,$ $$\frac x{|x|}=-1.$$

Comment: Yes i corrected it. But $f'(0)$ is undefined, how do we shown that $f'(0)$ is undefined in graph?

Comment: I don't know what's the point in downvoting the question

Answer (score 1):

Here $f(-x)=f(x)$, $f(0)=0$,$f(\pm 1)=\pi/2$; $f'(0^+)>0$, $f'(0^-)<0$, $f'(\pm 1)=\infty.$
So the curve is symmetric, passing through $x=0$ which is non-differentiable at $x=0$ (left/right derivatives are finite but unequal) and at $x=\pm 1$ (vertical tangent).ts domain is $[-1,1]$ and range is $[0, \pi/2]$. Hence, it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $y=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$\implies0\le y\le\pi$

Now for real $x^2\le1,\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge0\implies\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\cos y=\sqrt{1-x^2}\implies x^2=\cdots=\sin^2y\implies\sin y=|x|$  as $\sin y\ge0$

So, $f'(0^-)=?$